# How (and should I) proactively create synonyms that are more intuitive than the canonical tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

### Background

We currently have 17 questions tagged [daily-scrum](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-scrum), which is the formally correct name for the Scrum ceremony. However, colloquially many people call this meeting the [daily-standup](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-standup), so I [recently created](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/20010/4271) this tag because I couldn't figure out how to just create a synonym.

I think [daily-standup](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-standup) should point to [daily-scrum](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daily-scrum) because the latter is more canonical. However, I suspect that most users would find "daily standup" or even just "standup" to be more intuitive.

### Answer Me My Questions Three

With that background in mind, my questions are these:

1. Why can't I add a synonym directly?
2. Can we (and should we) proactively add synonyms for ease of use and/or search?
3. Can someone with super-cow powers link the synonym described above?

Comment: For #1, the link to create synonyms can be found on https://pm.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good evening

I believe [this](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tags/daily-scrum/synonyms) might answer your question:

> Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or
>   more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer
>   score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag,
>   can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved
>   when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they
>   reach a score of -2.

Based on the above, Id say:

1. Because the SE idea is to work based on suggestions + upvotes
2. Yes
3. Done

Cheers

Comment: The problem I was having was primarily that the way to *navigate* to the synonyms page is not very intuitive. Thanks for the help!